# Outlook Folder Browse Dialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, outlook, vsto

I'm hoping someone could help me with a quick point in the right direction. ALL I NEED is the Outlook folder browser dialog call. I am developing some plugins for Outlook using C# and this is a crucial part for both plugins. Hopefully, it is like a standard DialogResult that passes back folder information (selected folder) so that I can use this info for further processing. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the [`PickFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178985.aspx) method.